# no module ipaddress on python2.7.18

Tags: python, python-2.7, ip-address

I'm using python 2.7.18 on Windows, and i saw that `ipaddress` library was exclusively for python3 so i installed `py2-ipaddress` using pip. When i ran `pip list` into cmd, it shows `py2-ipaddress` as installed, but when i try `import ipaddress` into a python file i get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/x/Downloads/main (2).py", line 1, in <module>
    import ipaddress
ImportError: No module named ipaddress
```

Why i can't import it?

**EDIT :**
Actually, ipaddress works fine on python2.7.x, or it should, i installed now ipaddress using `pip install ipaddress`, it shows as installed when running `pip show ipaddress` but i still can't import it

Comment: Do you have different Python installations on your computer? pip might install the module for the wrong Python interpreter. And of course: Why do you still use Python 2? It's dead (unsupported) since over 2 years and that was announced over 10 years ago.

Comment: @Matthias, no, I don't think so. I ran `python -V` into cmd and shows only 1 version, `2.7.18`. But what i figured out now, is that i don't have `pyenv` working. I tried `pyenv` into cmd and it said it's not a recognizable intern or extern command

Answer (score 0):

@Matthias was right. It seems that my pip doesn't work properly, or i don't know how to use it properly. One quick fix, if you're running pycharm or any IDE with a built-in terminal is to install the module via IDE's terminal using `pip install <module>`.